# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'down')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**I created a header menu. It still worked in Material-UI V4. But I recently updated to Material-UI V5. But I have a error like this: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'down')**

```
import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";
import { Theme } from "@mui/system";

// NOTE: Styling header bar components

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    linkStyle: {
        textDecoration: "none",
        color: "white",
        marginLeft: 5,
    },
    desktopMenuStyle: {
        display: "display",

        [theme.breakpoints.down("mobile")]: {
            display: "none",
        },
    },
    mobileMenuStyle: {
        display: "none",

        "& .MuiList-root": {
            marginTop: 40,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down("laptop")]: {
            display: "block",
        },
    },
}));
```

[I have a error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68M4m.png)

Comment: V5 is a beta, so it can be a library error.

Answer (score 5):

write this code to the file include your component.

1.Import:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/styles";

import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

2. 

```
let theme = createTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

3. 

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <your component/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: It worked. Can you explain what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

For example write:

```
mobileMenuStyle: {
    display: "none",
    "& .MuiList-root": {
        marginTop: 40,
    }
},
"@media (max-width: 1440px)": {
    mobileMenuStyle: {
      display: "block"
     }
}
```

Instead of:

```
mobileMenuStyle: {
    display: "none",

    "& .MuiList-root": {
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("laptop")]: {
        display: "block",
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

encapsulate the datatable component with a theme provider

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/styles";
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

then

```
let theme = createTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

then

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
 < name of your data table compobebt >
</ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are directly importing/using a component and that component attempts to access data from the theme, you will get this error (or similar, depending what attributes you try to access within the theme).

The "theme" data from the ThemeProvider is *not* passed in to imported components (or components used directly in JSX), it is only passed into the *styling* of components or elements (via eg Styled Components or Emotion).

In other words, `<MyComponent />` will *not* receive any data from the theme, but ``` styled(MyComponent)``; ``` *will* receive the theme data.

This hung me up for a while so I hope it may help anyone else who stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 0):

1. import {makeStyles} from '@mui/styles';
2. import {Theme} from '@material-ui/core';

```
declare module '@material-ui/core' {
    interface DefaultTheme extends Theme{}
}

const useStyles = makeStyles( (theme : any) => ({

    yourcomponent : {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')] : {
         ///put your styles here 
        },

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

// import makeStyles from core

Comment: Please add an explanation