# MUI breakpoints not recognizing "theme.breakpoints.down"

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

### Goal: Hide navMenu when breakpoint is tablet and under, so I can replace with a hamburger menu

In terminal in VS code, it says compiled successfully, but in the browser I see:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'down')

I tried instructions here: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237115/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-down), with no luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  navMenu: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  },
}));

const Navbar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" style={{ backgroundColor: "#061B2E" }}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            Name
          </Typography>
          <Box className={classes.navMenu}>
            <Button color="inherit">Item 1</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Item 2</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Item 3</Button>
            <Button color="inherit">Item 4</Button>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Potential duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69678265/9449426).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, which version of MUI are you using? They're kind of shifting away from `makeSyles` in favor of styled components, but this method is still supported (we still use it exclusively on my team).  You may need to change your import statement to `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';`

Comment: I'm using "@mui/material": "^5.1.0". If there is a better way to go about this, how would I make this happen that's more beginner friendly? Even a link to a resource would be of great help

Comment: If you install the core package with `npm install @material-ui/core`, then change your import statement to what’s mentioned above it should work the way you have it.

Comment: One of the confusing things when starting with mui is the different packages. Most will be from `@mui/material`, but occasionally you’ll use some from `@mui/system` or `@material-ui/core`

Comment: Or if you want to use the newer styling engine in mui this part of the docs may be helpful https://mui.com/system/styled/

Comment: Ill take a look at that as well, thanks very much